# Laravel 8 is not reading the env values passed by docker-compose

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Hope you are well,

I have a project that I recently upgraded to laravel 8 from laravel 6.

it was dockerized both for dev and prod, after update unfortunately the app does not retrieve the env values that are passed by the docker-compose file and only works if I pass a .env file to the container.

this is while, inside the container I can still do:
`php artisan tinker` >> `print_r(env("DB_HOST"))` && `print_r($_ENV)`and see the env values even without passing the file itself

so the compose file passes the env values to the container but the laravel app does not pick them up

has anyone else faced this issue with laravel 8?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Could this be a config caching issue?

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment, I have already done the cache:clear & config:clear step but no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you accessing the values through `env()` or `config()`? If you're clearing the config cache, that won't resolve any issues when you access them through `env()`

Comment: interesting wise, both on artisan tinker (inside the container) return correct values, but when I attempt to for example do a CRUD task it returns DB Connection refused. This is while it allows me to do php artisan migrate and seed

Comment: @kolaente this is very interesting, I found the issue, it requires to do a `php artisan config:cache` on container creation as an entrypoint or last step on Dockerfile, otherwise it is not caching it at all, what made it also a bit more confusing was that it was sometimes copying my local cache to the machine which also misdirected me more. So in summary: 1- I needed to do a `php artisan config:clear` on my local, 2- I needed to add Dockerfile step `php artisan config:cache`. 3- rebuild the image and a brand new container for it

Comment: As your hint actually made me retry the right part of the code, if you want feel free to add a wrapup and some general hint as an answer to this question, otherwise I can also answer the question for later on

Comment: Added a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a caching issue. Please also make sure to access all env variables through `config()` calls and not to `env()` directly - that won't resolve if you're caching config.

This is the entrypoint script I'm using for production laravel images:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

artisan="/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan"
$artisan down
$artisan cache:clear

$artisan config:clear
$artisan config:cache

$artisan event:clear
$artisan event:cache

$artisan route:clear

$artisan view:clear

$artisan up

apache2-foreground
```

This clears all caches and caches them again when starting the container to ensure all values are up to date after a restart.

Comment: Thank you for the message and sorry for delay in approve, the sh is not necessary but it is a good practice, I personally do the steps with `php artisan ...` manually

This is a note for anyone who does not wanna follow the bash method